# CodeIgniter 'You did not select a file to upload' with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload

There are several Questions like this but I've checked them all and they don't appear to help me. I'm using CodeIgniter 2.1.4 and I'm trying to upload a file using ajax and the File Uploading Class. Whatever I try I always get the error 'You did not select a file to upload'.

I have the Controller as:

```
class Img extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

   public function index()
   {
          $this->load->view('img/index');
   }

   public function upload()
   {

          $imgfile = $_POST['imgfile'];

          $config['upload_path'] = 'upload/';
          $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
          $config['max_size']   = '100';
          $config['max_width']  = '1024';
          $config['max_height']  = '768';

          $this->load->library('upload', $config);
          if (!$this->upload->do_upload('imgfile'))
          {
                 $data = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors('', ''));
                 $result['success'] = 1;
                 $result['message'] = $data['error'];
          }
          else
          {
                 $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                 $result['success'] = 0;
                 $result['message'] = "Image Uploaded";
          }

          die(json_encode($result));

   }
```

And the View 'img/index' as:

```
<div id="alert" class="alert"> </div>

<form id="addForm" action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="imgfile" id="imgfile" size="20" />
<button type="submit" id="submit_add" name="submit_add">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#addForm").submit(function(e)
{

    e.preventDefault();

    var imgfile = $("#imgfile").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "?c=img&m=upload",
        dataType: "json",
        data: 'imgfile='+imgfile,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){

            $('#alert').empty().append(result.message);

        }

    });

});
</script>
```

EDIT: 
I'm including the malsup.com jQuery Form Plugin in the header

Comment: it will always give you error,if you post the image name and retrieve by $_POST.Try to use ajaxform submit.

Comment: Try `Malsup Form Plugin`

Comment: I am using Malsup's jQuery Form Plugin but cannot see how it needs to be configured to upload files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though this question is old I will provide a solution I found that may assist. I had been tied up trying to resolve this issues for about two week and in those two weeks I have scanned through this question with limited help until I found the solution.

To clarify.

I hit success while using $.ajaxFileUpload I read that you are using malsup. I have to clarify that I used both of them and neither was working for the 2 weeks period.

The solution to my problems was with the .htaccess. By removing its contents and testing the application again I found out that indeed it was working with index.php at the url. Therefore I sought to investigate. I found out that my file was indeed been uploaded but being lost during redirection.

I therefore suggest that :

1. Head over to .htaccess
2. Under RewriteBase change the location to the primary folder where your code is located.

at the end your .htaccess should look as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /CI_website/
#CI_website is folder where my codeigniter files are located.

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It seems to be the same problem I'm having, could you be more specific about which modification did you do?

Comment: @alucard : I have stated that you need to change the RewriteBase in the code above. Failure to correctly inform .htaccess will lead to your file being lost. hence codeigniter will throw the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add the value of your input type file to the post data. That's not how this works.

Check out [CodeIgniter and Uploadify](http://grafikkaos.co.uk/blog/article/108-integrating-uploadify-v3-and-codeigniter) if you really want to upload your files with async JS.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `$imgfile = $_POST['imgfile'];` to `$imgfile = $_FILES['imgfile'];`. Even so, you cant upload file using this, you can refer to [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) for submitting a form using ajax.

Comment: Changed the answer, thanks for your concern @AritraChakraborty

Comment: Submitting a form with ajax becomes a whole different beast if you want to upload files. This answer is really misleading.

Comment: Whats so `beast` in submitting a form in ajax? @mgrueter?

Comment: Submitting a form isn't the problem, it's submitting a form with a file upload thats making this question a tough one.

For starters: JavaScript can't read local files for security reasons, so how would you expect the backend script to get the file you want to upload? Just adding the filename to the post data isn't doing anything.

Comment: I think you missed the part where I mentioned that too about the post data. And to add to that, nothing is so `beasty` in `ajax form`. A beginner can do that too. Anyways, thanks. :D